# Workflow to perform bulk changes on list?

Tags: workflow, restart

I have a list with some 100 fixed entries. Already have a workflow on started that copies the rows and deletes them when a date columnis today.

What i need to do instead clean out a buch of columns and add week to some date columns and  clear out row history. Can I do all that and restart the workflow from the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in pure SharePoint designer workflow it's probably best to do it with the help of another list to keep track of which listitems and the have your workflow attached to that list and set to start on changes, then all you have to loop is set which item you've just processed. When you're done for the day, you can delay until next day and reset which item was last processed.

For more details see [Looping Through Items in a SharePoint List with SharePoint Designer Workflows](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.dk/2008/05/looping-through-items-in-sharepoint.html)

Whether this is a good idea is then another question. It'll be a lot more efficient to code the logic in a TimerJob, but ...