# Bulk Import on a SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, import

I'm curious as to how I would bulk import items on to an existing SharePoint list (if it is possible).  I understand you can create a new SharePoint list from an excel spreadsheet but that does not answer my question... see below.

First, lets assume a few things:

1) This data is coming from two different SharePoint lists
2) The data is formatted the same, so although columns may not be named the same the data types of those columns are the same (text box = text box, look up = look up, etc)
3) Lets call the first two lists: List 1 and List 2 and then the merged list we will call Merged List.
4) I am using SharePoint Designer 2013

I tried to export List 1 as a template and then build the first half of Merged List, which "works" sort of but I have to manually add all the items from List 2 in to the Merged List.  Which again, sort of works but right now this is test data of 5 records, obviously this will not be feasible with hundreds of records.

I have also tried to look at these solutions: [sol1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41833/workflow-to-perform-bulk-changes-on-list), [sol2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/bulk-data-upload-from-excel-file-to-sharepoint/9229b53e-0f50-432a-97e6-cd00b6281763), [sol3](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-import-excel-sharepoint/).  Sol3 has three different types of solutions that overlap with the first two however it also has two other solutions on the page that are interesting but don't quite fit my problem.

Is there some SharePoint method, whether it be an export function I'm not using, or some JavaScript we can write that will be able to combine two SharePoint lists in to a new SharePoint list?

Note: This could simple just not be possible, which is also an acceptable answer.  I just either need a solution to my problem or a clarification that this is not a possible task (excluding the attempts I have already done).

Answer (score 0):

How many items are in these lists?

Is this a one time operation (manual)? Or something that you need to automate.

1. You can display both lists in the DataSheet/Quick Edit view, select rows in the source, press Ctrl-C, go to the destination, click a row and press Ctrl-V. For large lists you would need to do this in batches.
2. Open the SharePoint lists in Microsoft Access and then either write a query to insert in one list from the other, or use copy and paste between the lists.

Comment: It would probably need to be automated.  I thought of doing it this way.  I appreciate the help though!  Do you think its possible to automate something like I'm asking (no is just as good as an answer).